# Is there anybody who was able to deploy a Laravel Sail Inertia Vite application ever?

Tags: laravel, deployment, vite, inertiajs

I have a Laravel Sail Inertia (vue3) app (with Vite) locally, and for 2 days I was not able to deploy on Ubuntu Apache server. At the moment it seems mission impossible. My questions to whom this setup seems more familiar than me:

1. Is deploying such an application can be thought of as a simple Laravel deployment  ? I mean, the steps needed, does not differ from a normal Laravel installation, with the only difference, that at the end I should run 'npm run build' ?
2. Or it significantly differs. If so, could somebody be so kind as to let me know, how to do it?

Thank you in advance.

I read all the available docs and forums, no help unfortunately...

Comment: It would help if you define the problem you‘re having.